# Get the size of a variable in Clang

Tags: c++, c, clang

With the `Clang` library, is there some available method to get the size of a variable (as if I used `sizeof()` in a regular C/C++ program ?

I am able (and this is what I want to do) to spot `VarDecl`, but at the moment I still can't find any method in the Clang namespace to get the size of my var spotted with the current `VarDecl`

Comment: If you are compiling in C or C++, sizeof() will work.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a macro

Comment: How about the [`clang::ASTRecordLayout::getSize()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTRecordLayout.html#a43a5213b8bf9e017693c3b25fd0fb767) method?

Comment: _clang::ASTRecordLayout::getSize()_ docs says it gets _record_ size.  Does that also apply correctly to type size, or variable size?

Comment: @mafso: OP uses a library which parse C++ file, so it cannot do `sizeof` on a type which is not declared in his source code.

Comment: That's it. What I am trying to do is to parse some C/C++ code with an analysis tool (OCLint). Therefore it's not usual C++ code and sizeof is not available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Size information for a type is stored in a TypeInfo associated with a given type.
You can get a corresponding FieldInfo pair from the ASTContext via the getTypeInfo function.
The first element of the pair is the size of the type in bits. The second element is the alignment of the type in bits.

```
bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *VD) {
    std::pair<uint64_t, unsigned> FieldInfo = VD->getASTContext().getTypeInfo(VD->getType());
    uint64_t TypeSize = FieldInfo.first;
    unsigned FieldAlign = FieldInfo.second;
    llvm::outs() << VD->getNameAsString() << " Size: " << TypeSize/8 << " Alignment: " << FieldAlign/8 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In recent versions of Clang, ASTContext::getTypeInfo also returns a [TypeInfo](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1TypeInfo.html) (currently on 3.6 myself). The principle is the same however.

Comment: For future readers, `TypeInfo::Width` does not actually yield the same value as `siezeof(T)`, e.g. in my case for a particular type the former is 64 while the latter is 4 though I have no idea why.

Comment: `TypeInfo::Width` is in bits, `sizeof(T)` is in bytes. That sure does not explain why you get 64 and not 32.